# Cisco Wireless LAN Controllerの冗長化構成について

Tags: network, wifi

ネットワーク構築初心者です。
CiscoのWLCの冗長化をする予定で、下記シスコのドキュメントを読んでいます。
https://www.cisco.com/c/ja_jp/td/docs/wl/wllancntrller/wllancntrllersw/cg/001/b_cg80/b_cg80_chapter_010010100.html#ID148

> すべてのコントローラは、同じ仮想インターフェイス IP アドレスで設定する必要があります。 （注）  必要に応じて、仮想インターフェイス
>   IP アドレスを変更するには、[Controller] > [Interfaces] ページで仮想インターフェイス名を編集します。 （注） 
>   モビリティ
>   グループ内のすべてのコントローラが同じ仮想インターフェイスを使用していない場合、コントローラ間ローミングが動作しているように見えても、ハンドオフが完了せず、クライアントの接続はしばらくの間切断されます。

「すべてのコントローラは、同じ仮想インターフェイス IP アドレスで設定する必要があります。」と記載があるのですが、ドキュメント内に仮想インターフェイス IP アドレスの設定方法がないように思えます。
お手数ですが、GUIおよびCLIでのWLCの仮想インターフェイス IP アドレスの設定方法について、実際のコンフィグ例など、もう少し詳しく教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11203011121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リンク先の右上にある検索窓から「仮想インターフェイス」で検索するといくつかページがヒットしますが、こちらは違いますか？
実際の設定例までは見当たりませんが、GUIとCLIでの設定方法が記述されているようです。

[Cisco Wireless LAN Controller コンフィギュレーション ガイド リリース 8.0 - 仮想インターフェイスの設定](https://www.cisco.com/c/ja_jp/td/docs/wl/wllancntrller/wllancntrllersw/cg/001/b_cg80/b_cg80_chapter_011110.html?dtid=osscdc000334)

Comment: このページ自身には差は無いと思いますが、こちらの方がマイナーバージョンが少しだけ新しいものです。[Cisco Wireless LAN Controller コンフィギュレーション ガイド リリース 8.2 - 仮想インターフェイスの設定](https://www.cisco.com/c/ja_jp/td/docs/wireless/controller/8-2/config-guide/b_cg82/b_cg82_chapter_011111.html)

Comment: こちらの方がもう少し詳しく設定方法が記載されていますね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

[Cisco Wireless LAN Controller コンフィギュレーション ガイド リリース 7.3](https://www.cisco.com/c/ja_jp/td/docs/wl/wllancntrller/5500wlcntrllers/cg/003/b_cg73/b_cg73_chapter_011.html#d108768e1113a1635)　のような資料では足りないですか？

『
管理インターフェイスの設定（GUI）
ステップ 1      [Controller] > [Interfaces] の順に選択して、[Interfaces] ページを開きます。
ステップ 2      [management] リンクをクリックします。
[Interfaces > Edit] ページが表示されます。
ステップ 3      管理インターフェイスのパラメータを設定します。
ステップ 4      [Save Configuration] をクリックします。
ステップ 5      管理インターフェイスまたは仮想インターフェイスに何らかの変更を行ったときに変更を有効にするには、コントローラをリブートします。』
というような説明が書かれています。（これはCisco 5500 シリーズ コントローラのマニュアルなので、必要に応じてお使いの機器に合ったマニュアルをお読みください）